# Prevent "The Podfile contains framework targets..." warning

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Whenever I do a `pod install` I get this warning:

> [!] The Podfile contains framework targets, for which the Podfile does
>   not contain host targets (targets which embed the framework). If this
>   project is for doing framework development, you can ignore this
>   message. Otherwise, add a target to the Podfile that embeds these
>   frameworks to make this message go away (e.g. a test target).

My project is for framework development and warning says I can ignore it but I hate warnings that appear for something that doesn't need to be warned about so is there any workaround to make this warning go away?

My Podfile looks like this:

```
workspace 'myworkspace.xcworkspace'
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'framework' do
    use_frameworks!
    project 'framework/framework.xcodeproj'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5', :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'Serpent', '~> 1.0', :inhibit_warnings => true
end

target 'demo-objc-uitests' do
    use_frameworks!
    inherit! :search_paths
    project 'demo-objc/demo-objc.xcodeproj'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5', :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'Serpent', '~> 1.0', :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'myframework', :path => 'myframework.podspec'
end

target 'demo-swift-uitests' do
    use_frameworks!
    inherit! :search_paths
    project 'demo-swift/demo-swift.xcodeproj'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5', :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'Serpent', '~> 1.0', :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'myframework', :path => 'myframework.podspec'
end
```